# Text is added at wrong caret position in codemirror text area

Tags: javascript, text, codemirror

Initilization Code

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(".edit-box", this.element)[0], { 
   mode: "text/html", 
   lineNumbers: true, 
   lineWrapping: true 
});
```

On adding text in editor sometimes the text is added in the wrong position as shown in the GIF below
This issue is tested on version 3.21.0 and 5.48.4
Steps to reproduce.

1. Open the editor add text in it.
2. Click on the end of any word and then click on the start of the next word.
3. Type anything, it will be added to wrong position.

[image]

Any idea what is causing this problem?
And how to fix it?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: any idea how to fix it ?\

Comment: post to https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report of a third party library